# Cannot pass input value to another input value via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I wanted to pass the value of input field to another input field with its value via javascript. I wrote code as shown below.

First input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient" name="recipientName" value="RecipientName" onkeyup="recipient()"/>
```

Second input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="recipientHidden" name="recipientName"/>
```

Js Code

```
function recipient(){
   var recipientNameValue = document.getElementById('recipient').value;
   document.getElementById('recipientHidden').value = recipientNameValue;
   console.log(document.getElementById('recipientHidden').value);
}
```

When I open console, there is no value in the console. When I click on the first input field, value is printed.

How can I get it instantly ?

Comment: Your code works flawlessly over here. Did you get an error in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, but it will only log the value on key up. You can log the value immediately by calling the `recipient()` function right away:

```js
function recipient() {
  var recipientNameValue = document.getElementById('recipient').value;
  document.getElementById('recipientHidden').value = recipientNameValue;
  console.log(document.getElementById('recipientHidden').value);
}

// Call function straight away
recipient()
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient" name="recipientName" value="RecipientName" onkeyup="recipient()" />

<input type="hidden" id="recipientHidden" name="recipientName" />
```